# HttpContext.Request.Form with igniteui hierarchial grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an `MVC 3` app with an [IgniteUi](https://github.com/IgniteUI) hierarchial grid that is used nearly exactly like this [example](http://www.igniteui.com/hierarchical-grid/editing-dataset). The only difference is my nested grid has paging.

So when I mark records for deletion that's on page 1 then go to page 2 and mark records for deletion and click the save button, the only records that are in the HttpContext.Request.Form["ig_transactions"] form are the records that were selected on the current page (i.e I select record #1 on page 1 then i go to page 2 and select record #6 and click save only record #6 is in `HttpContext.Request.Form["ig_transactions"]`).

I'm thinking i need to store my values into the form named ig_transactions every time the delete button is clicked, then when the Save button is clicked, the HttpContext.Request.Form["ig_transactions"] collection will have all the records selected regardless of what page i was on in the nested grid.

How do I write to this form via `javascript`/`jQuery`? Any sample would be fine, so this is really a javascript question and not one about [IgniteUi](https://github.com/IgniteUI).

Thank you.